# Errors when trying to access greenplum table using pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, greenplum

I am trying to sign onto a server and pull back data to locally build a model in python. I'm using the pyspark library - but I keep getting the same error. Here is the code I am running, without error, so I know that I've installed the .jar files correctly:

```
import pyspark
print(pyspark.__file__)
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingQueueStream") 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.read.format('io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider')

sc.stop()
```

It provides this as the output indicating the jar is correctly installed:

```
<pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader at 0x10819cd10>
```

I can run this in scala without error, it pulls back the table that I am requesting:

```
val gscReadOptionMap = Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:postgresql://12.3.45.678:9101/code",
  "user" -> "my_name",
  "password" -> "password",
  "dbschema" -> "schema",
  "dbtable" -> "table",
  "partitionColumn" -> "max"
)
val gpdf = spark.read.format("greenplum").options(gscReadOptionMap).load()
```

And it provides the following output:

```
gpdf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [output_code: string, input_code: string ... 11 more fields]
```

But when I try to put the database sign-on into python I keep getting the same error:

```
import pyspark
print(pyspark.__file__)
from pyspark.sql import DataFrameReader
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingQueueStream") 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.read.format('io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider')

source_df = sqlContext.read.format('io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider').options(
          url='jdbc:postgresql://12.3.45.678:9101/code',
          dbschema='schema',
          dbtable = 'table',
          user='my_name',
          password='password',
          driver='org.postgresql.Driver',
          partitionColumn='max').load()

sc.stop()
```

Here is the error, in usual python fashion the error is super long:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 165, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o111.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:549)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$21.apply(DataSource.scala:533)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:533)
    ... 16 more
```

I have the 'greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar' and 'postgresql-42.2.4.jre7.jar' being brought in... I'm not sure what I am doing wrong?

edit: 
I am running the jars in python 2 ways and it has no bearing on the error.

```
import os 
os.getcwd() 
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--master local[*] pyspark-shell --jars /Users/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar, /Users/postgresql-42.2.4.jre7.jar'
```

I've also run:

```
%%bash 
export GSC_JAR=/Users/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar export POSTGRES_JAR=/Users/postgresql-42.2.4.jre7.jar 
spark-shell --jars ${GSC_JAR}, ${POSTGRES_JAR}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help and suggestions. The pyspark connector / loader does not work in any interface except the terminal. i.e. Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your pyspark didn't load the greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar

Suggestion:
Check whether your pyspark command is passing the argument "--jars" with the path to greenplum-sparkXXXX.jar.  The example below uses "GSC_JAR" environment variable that points to the file path of greenplum-spark_2.11-*.jar with the directory "/code". So please make appropriate changes to the GSC_JAR env variable.

```
root@master:/usr/spark-2.1.0#GSC_JAR=$(ls /code/greenplum-spark_2.11-*.jar)
root@master:/usr/spark-2.1.0#pyspark --jars "${GSC_JAR}"
```

Thanks,
Kong
Example of using Pyspark with Greenplum:
https://greenplum-spark-connector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-pyspark.html

Comment: I am running the jars in python 2 ways and it has no bearing on the error:

import os
os.getcwd()
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--master local[*] pyspark-shell --jars /Users/sarahewing/Documents/OnBoarding/python/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar, /Users/sarahewing/Documents/OnBoarding/python/postgresql-42.2.4.jre7.jar'

I've also run:

%%bash

export GSC_JAR=/Users/sarahewing/Documents/OnBoarding/python/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar
export POSTGRES_JAR=/Users/sarahewing/Documents/OnBoarding/python/postgresql-42.2.4.jre7.jar
spark-shell --jars ${GSC_JAR}, ${POSTGRES_JAR}

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help.  i tried out the existing scala example from the greenplum-spark connector docs using pyspark.  this is slightly different than your example (i am not using SQLContext), but at one point the following worked for me:

user@spark-client$ pyspark --jars

> > > gscPythonOptions = {
> > >                "url": "jdbc:postgresql://gpmaster.domain/tutorial",
> > >                "user": "user2",
> > >                "password": "pivotal",
> > >                "dbschema": "faa",
> > >                "dbtable": "otp_c",
> > >                "partitionColumn": "airlineid"
> > >           }
> > >
> > > gpdf = spark.read.format("greenplum").options(**gscPythonOptions).load()

after which these commands worked for me:

> > > gpdf.printSchema()
> > >
> > > gpdf.count()

Answer (score 0):

Please verify greenplum-spark connector jar is loaded by pyspark

Action:
Use sc.getConf().getAll() function to verify the spark.repl.local.jars is referring to the appropriate jar(s).

```
>>> sc.getConf().getAll()
[('spark.app.id', 'app-20180718183929-0000'), ('spark.jars',         
'file:///code/usecase1/data/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar'),     
('spark.master', 'spark://master:7077'), ('spark.rdd.compress', 
'True'), ('spark.driver.host', 'master'), 
('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'), 
('spark.repl.local.jars', 'file:///code/usecase1/data/greenplum- 
spark_2.11-1.4.0.jar'), ('spark.driver.port', '38611'), 
('spark.executor.id', 'driver'), ('spark.submit.deployMode', 
'client'), ('spark.app.name', 'PySparkShell'), 
('spark.ui.showConsoleProgress', 'true')]
```